# How to use $setOnInsert on update and return the document in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm using Java MongoDB Driver. The version is 3.0.3.

I'm trying to use $setOnInsert on update but I want to return inserted or updated document.

I have a `userId`, `createdDate` and `modifiedDate` fields. When the document doesn't exist, I'm gonna create one, but when it does, I'm gonna just update the modifiedDate field. I know the `db.collection.update()` doesn't return document, but that's the only way I see I can upsert. Below is the query I'm using for `update`:

```
db.collection.update(
    { userId: <userId> },
    {
      $set: { modifiedDate: <date> },
      $setOnInsert: { createdDate: <date> }
    },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

I know MongoDB has a `findAndModify` which you can use to update and return the updated document.

Is there any way I can use the `findAndModify` with `$setOnInsert` or to use the `update` to return the "upserted" document?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sure, `$setOnInsert` will work with `findAndModify` just fine.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK, `findAndModify` works just fine and returns the "upserted" document.